# Как убрать кавычки при инсерте или селекте по дефолту в БД Postgress 14 версии?

Tags: postgresql

Подскажите,есть ли решение.
По дефолту,можно юзать колонки только в кавычках,например
insert into a ("a","b")
Можно как-то сделать так,чтобы эти кавычки не использовать по дефолту?

Comment: эм....... шшшто?  А настоящая проблема в чём?

Comment: Если имена столбцов состоят только из латинских букв, и не совпадают с ключевыми словами, то кавычки не обязательны нужны.

Comment: *По дефолту,можно юзать колонки только в кавычках* Кто вам сказал такую глупость? Дефолт тут может быть только один - синтаксическая корректность полученного запроса. Если он корректен без кавычек - их можно не использовать.

Comment: Настоящая проблема в том,что Pentaho нинак не воспроизводит кавычки.То есть она интерпретирует любые DDL операции строго без кавычек.

Comment: Тогда в какой-то момент это может стать проблемой, т.к. могут быть случаи, когда кавычки просто необходимы, чтобы парсер мог однозначно определить, что это наименование колонки, а не ключевое слово или какой-нибудь алиас (как написал Герман Борисов и Akina).

Comment: Я все понимаю..алиасы не пройдут.
Спс,в целом я так и думал,что этого не обойти